# Which tool makes transliteration of Hebrew words for documents?

Tags: gratis, language, ipad-app

Is there any tool that translates Hebrew characters into Latin characters?

Not single word, but documents or many words.

The OS is iOS for IPad, I need a GUI, format is docx, and I would not pay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a web-based [Automatic Hebrew Transliteration utility](http://www.alittlehebrew.com/transliterate/) that will transliterate or transcribe Hebrew words into Roman letters readable by English speakers. If you can open your docx document and copy the text, you can paste it there and it will provide you with the transliteration.